# CSS does not fit

Tags: html, css

I am building a page example on `this` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/dnypmx12/2/)

The scrollbar (horizontal) appears :

[image]

I want this page to be fit on the browser, to there should not a scrollbar. please help _/_
[image]

Comment: That's a lot of CSS to sift through.  Why don't you just set a proper size for your page?

Comment: On line 152 in the CSS,  `width: calc(100%-260px);` you must change this to have spaces around the minus like `width: calc(100% - 260px);` and that'll fix it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because of this section:

```
#content{
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100%-260px);
    left: 260px;
}
```

You can change the `left` to `margin-left` which will solve your issue, like below (you can also get rid of the `width: calc(100%-260px);` then):

```
#content{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 260px;
}
```